# run perl scripts as different user without mod_perl

Tags: apache, perl

I'm using [web-console](http://www.web-console.org) in my project. It's a console in the browser where I can type some commands and it runs them in the server with user www-data.
The installation instructions say

> If your web server configured to execute Perl scripts under specific
>   user account, please make sure that this user has write permissions
>   for recently created directory.

is it possible to run perl scripts in the server with a user different than www-data? I can't see it in the apache docs. I'm using apache 2 with this configuration (without mod_perl):

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
<Directory /var/www/myproject/public_html/webconsole>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/suexec.html

Comment: thanks  @Quentin I'm working on this. I thought I had to add an option to that directory. I'm marking this as solved

Answer (score 1):

Would this be of any help: "The suEXEC feature provides Apache users the ability to run CGI and SSI programs under user IDs different from the user ID of the calling web server. Normally, when a CGI or SSI program executes, it runs as the same user who is running the web server."

Source: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html